# CodeCoverage in .Net core project -MSBuild error

Tags: .net, .net-core, visual-studio-code, azure-devops, msbuild

I have to create a code coverage in azure devops. So I am following the instructions from below url.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/run-quality-tests-build-pipeline/6-perform-code-coverage

But I have got an error on the following command .

```
MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="*" dotnet test --no-build \
  --configuration Release \
  /p:CollectCoverage=true \
  /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura \
  /p:CoverletOutput=./TestResults/Coverage/
```

Error- MSBUILD : error MSB1011: Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains
more than one project or solution file.

Can any one tell me how to fix this please?

Comment: Error _Specify which project or solution file to use because this folder contains more than one project or solution file_ tells you what to do exactly

Answer (score 1):

> CodeCoverage in .Net core project -MSBuild error

Just as the error message suggests that because the current work folder contains more than one project or solution files.

To resolve this issue, you should specify the project file in your command:

```
 MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="*" dotnet test projects/test1/test1.csproj --no-build \
  --configuration Release \
  /p:CollectCoverage=true \
  /p:CoverletOutputFormat=cobertura \
  /p:CoverletOutput=./TestResults/Coverage/
```

You could check the document [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) for some more details.

Comment: It looks good now, Thank you so much for your help !